# using python urllib and beautiful soup to extract information from html site

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to extract some information from this website i.e. the line which says:

Scale(Virgo + GA + Shapley):      29 pc/arcsec =  0.029 kpc/arcsec =   1.72 kpc/arcmin =   0.10 Mpc/degree

but everything after the : is variable depending on galtype.

I have written a code which used beautifulsoup and urllib and returns sone information, but i am struggling to reduce the data further to just the information I want. How do I get just the information I want?

```
galname='M82'
a='http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/objsearch?objname='+galname+'&extend'+\
   '=no&hconst=73&omegam=0.27&omegav=0.73&corr_z=1&out_csys=Equatorial&out_equinox=J2000.0&obj'+\
   '_sort=RA+or+Longitude&of=pre_text&zv_breaker=30000.0&list_limit=5&img_stamp=YES'

print a
import urllib
f = urllib.urlopen(a)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(f)

soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Virgo')) and soup.find_all(text=re.compile('GA')) and soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Shapley'))
```

Comment: Don't use `urllib`,  it's a terrible API. Use `requests`,  it's practically standard lib and it's a beautiful API.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: there is line which reads 'D (Virgo + GA + Shapley)   :' I need this line (mainly the first number form the line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a regular expression pattern that would help `BeautifulSoup` to find the appropriate node, then, extract the number using saving groups:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"D \(Virgo \+ GA \+ Shapley\)\s+:\s+([0-9\.]+)")
print pattern.search(soup.find(text=pattern)).group(1)
```

Prints `5.92`.

---

Besides, usually I'm against using regular expressions to parse HTML, but, since this is a text search and we are not going to use regular expressions to match opening or closing tags or anything related to the structure that HTML provides - you can just apply your pattern to the HTML source of the page without involving an HTML parser:

```
data = f.read()
pattern = re.compile(r"D \(Virgo \+ GA \+ Shapley\)\s+:\s+([0-9\.]+)")
print pattern.search(data).group(1)
```

Comment: If I want to search for a different text value such as the error (which is 5 or 6 charahcters later do i alter the part of the code which is after \s+:\s+([0-9\.]+) ? im not familiar with what the part of the code does.

Comment: @user2201043 I think your regular expression would transform into `D \(Virgo \+ GA \+ Shapley\)\s+:\s+([0-9\.]+)\s+\+/\-\s+([0-9\.]+)`. Then use `groups()` or `group(1)` and `group(2)` to get the values.

Comment: I assume where the above says \s+([0-9\.]+) it is looking for numbers? but i am trying to use this code

 pattern = re.compile(r"\Classifications \s+:")
a=soup.find(text=pattern)
print pattern.search(soup.find(text=pattern)).group(0)

but I need the next information to be letters and not numbers, how do i do this?

Comment: @user2201043 or, you can also use `\d+\.\d+` to match a float.